Have text citations refer to a bibliographic entry in a `\newrefsection`
I'm preparing a document with a cover letter followed by publication lists using biblatex-publist.
Citations in the cover letter are not linking to the citation in the bibliography. I presume it is because I am using \newrefsection to periodically to add different types of publication types (articles, book chapters). This has the virtue of using \getsectioncount to provide a total for each section, but it seems to then not permit a link between a text citation before all the \newrefsections and its bibliographic entry. Is there any way to square this circle?
Thank you.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\publistbasestyle{mla}
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist, 
doi=true,
date=year, 
url=true,
hyperref=true,
plnumbering=local,
linktitles=doi,
citestyle=authoryear,
maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}




\begin{filecontents}{bib1.bib}
@Book{knuth1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book },
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Article{greenwade1993,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib2.bib}
@Book{goossens1993,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib1.bib}
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}
  Here is my cover letter in which I would like to cite \parencite{goossens1993} and \parencite{greenwade1993},
  
\tableofcontents
\subsection*{Publications}

\subsubsection*{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
\begin{refsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
\nocite{*}
Total \GetSectionCount
\printbibliography[heading=none,type={article}]
\end{refsection}
\subsubsection*{Books}
\begin{refsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Books}
\nocite{*}
Total \GetSectionCount
\printbibliography[heading=none,type={book}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}


I use refsections with hyperlinks all the time, so there is certainly no issue there. My crystal ball suggests you're misusing \newrefsection, but, without seeing some code which produces the issue, all anybody can really do is guess. Even crystal balls have their limitations. :)-

Oh man, I am an idiot. Code is there now.

What would really solve my problem is if there were a way I could use \newrefsegment instead of \newrefsection. That works great, but it does not count the references inside a refsegment. Is that possible?

Sorry. I've already said several stupid things tonight, so I'm probably missing something obvious, but where does your example use \newrefsection?

I would say in order to make the references actually accessible, you need to refer to them numerically and use a global numbering scheme. Otherwise references will be very hard to follow.
As of version 2.11 (2024-07-02), you can employ \citesecitem to this end, as in the following example. Note that I have adapted your example to really use refsections and split up the bibliographies for the section to get proper numbering:
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \newcommand*\publistbasestyle{mla}
    \usepackage[
    style=publist, 
    doi=true,
    date=year, 
    url=true,
    hyperref=true,
    plnumbering=global,
    linktitles=doi,
    maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
    
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname-books.bib}
        @Book{knuth1990,
            author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
            title     = {The {\TeX}book },
            year      = {1990},
            isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
            publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
        }
        
        @Book{goossens1993,
            author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
            title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
            year      = "1993",
            publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
            address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
        }
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname-articles.bib}
        @Article{greenwade1993,
        author  = "George D. Greenwade",
        title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
        year    = "1993",
        journal = "TUGBoat",
        volume  = "14",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "342--351"
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        citecolor=blue,
        filecolor=blue,
        linkcolor=blue,
        urlcolor=blue
    }
       
    \begin{document}
        Here is my cover letter in which I would like to cite \citesecitem{goossens1993} and \citesecitem{greenwade1993},
        
        \tableofcontents
        \subsection*{Publications}
        
        \subsubsection*{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
        \newrefsection[\jobname-articles]
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
        \nocite{*}
        Total \GetSectionCount
        \printbibliography[heading=none,type={article}]
        
        \subsubsection*{Books}
        \newrefsection[\jobname-books]
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Books}
        \nocite{*}
        Total \GetSectionCount
        \printbibliography[heading=none,type={book}]
        
    \end{document}

Result:


Prior to v. 2.11 the same can be achieved with the following hack which writes local reference numbers to a global helper file:
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \newcommand*\publistbasestyle{mla}
    \usepackage[
    style=publist, 
    doi=true,
    date=year, 
    url=true,
    hyperref=true,
    plnumbering=global,
    linktitles=doi,
    maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
    
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname-books.bib}
        @Book{knuth1990,
            author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
            title     = {The {\TeX}book },
            year      = {1990},
            isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
            publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
        }
        
        @Book{goossens1993,
            author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
            title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
            year      = "1993",
            publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
            address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
        }
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname-articles.bib}
        @Article{greenwade1993,
        author  = "George D. Greenwade",
        title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
        year    = "1993",
        journal = "TUGBoat",
        volume  = "14",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "342--351"
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        citecolor=blue,
        filecolor=blue,
        linkcolor=blue,
        urlcolor=blue
    }
    
    % Add some helper commands to access local citation numbers
    \makeatletter
    \renewrobustcmd{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
        % Print labelnumber as actual number, plus item total
        \number\numexpr\csuse{bpl@itemtotal}+#1+\csuse{bpl@shift@itemtotal}\relax%
        \if@filesw%
            \immediate\write\bpl@bpxfile{%
                \csedef{bpl@savecite:\thefield{entrykey}}{\number\numexpr\csuse{bpl@itemtotal}+#1+\csuse{bpl@shift@itemtotal}\relax}%
            }%
        \fi
    }%
    \newcommand*{\getcite}[1]{%
        \ifcsdef{bpl@savecite:#1}{\mkbibbrackets{\csuse{bpl@savecite:#1}}}{\textbf{[???]}}%
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{document}
        Here is my cover letter in which I would like to cite \getcite{goossens1993} and \getcite{greenwade1993},
        
        \tableofcontents
        \subsection*{Publications}
        
        \subsubsection*{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
        \newrefsection[\jobname-articles]
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
        \nocite{*}
        Total \GetSectionCount
        \printbibliography[heading=none,type={article}]
        
        \subsubsection*{Books}
        \newrefsection[\jobname-books]
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Books}
        \nocite{*}
        Total \GetSectionCount
        \printbibliography[heading=none,type={book}]
        
    \end{document}


Achieving the same with author-year references is significantly harder, but as said I don't think it makes much sense usability-wise.

The next version of the package (2.11) will feature a new command \citesecitem which will produce the above output out of the box.

When will that be released do you think?

@spindoctor not too soon, but you can grab the updated versions of biblatex-publist.bbx and biblatex-publist.cbx from the repository. Testing and feedback prior to release would be very welcome anyway.

OK, I will see if I can get them to work. Please note: In your code, the numeric citations are not hyperlinking to the reference. Is that working on your end?

No this is not supported (yet).

I have something that is close to providing everything I need, but it \newrefsegment is printing the name of the bibresource. Filed a question here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/721628/newrefsegment-prints-title-of-bib-file

As to hyperlinks: Since refsections are decidedly local also with regard to the anchors, this would be nontrivial to achieve. I am not sure it is worth the hassle.
