\newrefsegment prints title of bib file
I am using the biblatex-publist package to format a file with a cover letter followed by lists of publications. publist is amazing and I am very close to having what I need.
However, when using \newrefsegment adding a bibresource for each segment, the name of the bibresource file is printed.
Is there a way to suppress the name of the bibresource using \newrefsegment?
The reason refsegments are working so well for me is because it is permitting me to create linked text and parenthetical citations in the cover letter preceding the bibliographies of publications.
I have been fighting with various other problems here but opened up a new question for transparency and clarity.
\documentclass{article}
    
\newcommand*\publistbasestyle{mla}
\usepackage[
    style=publist, 
    doi=true,
    date=year, 
    url=true,
    hyperref=true,
    plnumbering=local,
    linktitles=doi,
    maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-books.bib}
@Book{knuth1990,
            author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
            title     = {The {\TeX}book },
            year      = {1990},
            isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
            publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
        
@Book{goossens1993,
            author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
            title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
            year      = "1993",
            publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
            address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-articles.bib}
        @Article{greenwade1993,
        author  = "George D. Greenwade",
        title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
        year    = "1993",
        journal = "TUGBoat",
        volume  = "14",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        citecolor=blue,
        filecolor=blue,
        linkcolor=blue,
        urlcolor=blue
}
\addbibresource{\jobname-articles.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-books.bib}
\begin{document}
        Here is my cover letter in which I would like to cite \parencite{goossens1993} and \parencite{greenwade1993},
        \tableofcontents
        \subsection*{Publications}
        \subsubsection*{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
\newrefsegment[\jobname-articles]
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[heading=none,type={article}]
        \subsubsection*{Books}
\newrefsegment[\jobname-books]
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Books}
        \nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none,type={book}]
        
\end{document}


\newrefsegement does not take any argument (as opposed to \newrefsection).
